# ZEIT Now - command doesn't work for NextJS

Tags: vercel

I'm trying to deploy this [example NextJS app](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/deploying-a-nextjs-app), but whenever I run the *now* command, I get the following error:

```
At C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\now.ps1:5 char:13
+     *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
+             ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\now.ps1:8 char:3
+ if [ -x "$basedir/pwsh" ]; then
+   ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\now.ps1:8 char:5
+ if [ -x "$basedir/pwsh" ]; then
+     ~
Missing type name after '['.
At C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\now.ps1:9 char:20
+ ... sedir/pwsh"  "$basedir/../Data/global/node_modules/.bin/now.ps1" "$@"
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '"$basedir/../Data/global/node_modules/.bin/now.ps1"' in 
expression or statement.
At C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\now.ps1:9 char:72
+ ... sedir/pwsh"  "$basedir/../Data/global/node_modules/.bin/now.ps1" "$@"
+                                                                      ~~~~
Unexpected token '"$@"' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I followed all the steps by creating a *now.json* and *next.config.js* file, but I'm still unsuccessful with my attempts of deploying this example NextJS app.

To diagnose the issue, I've tried installing now *globally* by running this command:

`yarn global add now`

but this didn't help in resolving the issue.

Would there be a step I'm missing? Thanks for the help.

EDIT: btw, I am on a Windows machine and I ran the command on PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the package management tool [yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6902). I uninstalled it from yarn and installed it globally using *npm* instead.